# Scrapy: why does my response object not have a body_as_unicode method?

Tags: python, scrapy

I wrote a spider, that worked brilliantly the first time. The second time I tried to run it, it didn't venture beyond the `start_urls`. I tried to `fetch` the url in `scrapy shell` and create a `HtmlXPathSelector` object from the returned response. That is when I got the error

So the steps were:
`

```
[scrapy shell] fetch('http://example.com') #its something other than example.
[scrapy shell] from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
[scrapy shell] hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Traceback:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-a486208adf1e> in <module>()
----> 1 HtmlXPathSelector(response)

/home/codefreak/project-r42catalog/env-r42catalog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/selector/lxmlsel.pyc in __init__(self, response, text, namespaces, _root, _expr)
     29                 body=unicode_to_str(text, 'utf-8'), encoding='utf-8')
     30         if response is not None:
---> 31             _root = LxmlDocument(response, self._parser)
     32 
     33         self.namespaces = namespaces

/home/codefreak/project-r42catalog/env-r42catalog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/selector/lxmldocument.pyc in __new__(cls, response, parser)
     25         if parser not in cache:
     26             obj = object_ref.__new__(cls)
---> 27             cache[parser] = _factory(response, parser)
     28         return cache[parser]
     29 

/home/codefreak/project-r42catalog/env-r42catalog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/selector/lxmldocument.pyc in _factory(response, parser_cls)
     11 def _factory(response, parser_cls):
     12     url = response.url
---> 13     body = response.body_as_unicode().strip().encode('utf8') or '<html/>'
     14     parser = parser_cls(recover=True, encoding='utf8')
     15     return etree.fromstring(body, parser=parser, base_url=url)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'body_as_unicode'
```

Am I overlooking something very obvious or stumbled upon a bug in scrapy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`body_as_unicode` is a method of [TextResponse](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.TextResponse). TextResponse, or one of its subclasses such as HtmlResponse, will be created by scrapy if the http response contains textual content.

```
In [1]: fetch('http://scrapy.org')
...
In [2]: type(response)
Out[2]: scrapy.http.response.html.HtmlResponse
...
In [3]: fetch('http://www.scrapy.org/site-media/images/logo.png')
...
In [4]: type(response)
Out[4]: scrapy.http.response.Response
```

In your case, the most likely explanation is that scrapy believes the response does not contain text.

Does the HTTP response from the server correctly set the Content-Type header? Does it render correctly in a browser? These questions will help understand if it's expected behavior or a bug.

Comment: I figured it out, it has got something to do with the httpcache on mongo.

Comment: I see, that would make sense why it worked the first time. Probably the requests aren't getting created correctly from the cache.

Comment: I am using https://github.com/scrapinghub/scmongo/ for caching pages in mongo, do you have any idea on ensuring that requests / responses get created properly?
Or Can I force the retrieved object to be TextResponse (short term solution)?