# Scrapy crawl spider stopped working

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

Prehistory:
I'm running Scrapy version 0.16.2 on Python 2.7.2+ and it is on Linux Mint. 
A few days ago [I had this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025427/scrapy-crawler-spider-doesnt-follow-links) 
and with help I managed to overcome it. For a few moments Crawler worked as it should:

```
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: 
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [basketsp17] INFO: Spider opened
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [basketsp17] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6024
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6081
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [basketsp17] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.euroleague.net/main/results/by-date> from <GET http://www.euroleague.net/main/results/by-date/>
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [basketsp17] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.euroleague.net/main/results/by-date> (referer: None)
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [basketsp17] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.euroleaguebasketball.net': <GET http://www.euroleaguebasketball.net/>
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [basketsp17] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.eurocupbasketball.com': <GET http://www.eurocupbasketball.com/>
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [basketsp17] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.euroleague.tv': <GET http://www.euroleague.tv/>
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [basketsp17] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.euroleaguestore.net': <GET http://www.euroleaguestore.net/>
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [basketsp17] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'fantasychallenge.euroleague.net': <GET http://fantasychallenge.euroleague.net/>
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [basketsp17] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.facebook.com': <GET http://www.facebook.com/TheEuroleague>
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [basketsp17] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.youtube.com': <GET http://www.youtube.com/euroleague>
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [basketsp17] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'euroleaguedevotion.ourtoolbar.com': <GET http://euroleaguedevotion.ourtoolbar.com/>
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [basketsp17] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'euroleague.synapticdigital.com': <GET http://euroleague.synapticdigital.com/>
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [basketsp17] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'twitter.com': <GET http://twitter.com/Euroleague>
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [basketsp17] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'kort.es': <GET http://kort.es/ulpGt>
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [basketsp17] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'adserver.itsfogo.com': <GET http://adserver.itsfogo.com/click.aspx?zoneid=136145>
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [basketsp17] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.euroleague.net/> (referer: http://www.euroleague.net/main/results/by-date)
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [basketsp17] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.euroleague.net/devotion/home> (referer: http://www.euroleague.net/main/results/by-date)
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [basketsp17] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.euroleague.net/euroleaguenews/transactions/2013-14-signings> (referer: http://www.euroleague.net/main/results/by-date)
2013-11-23 01:02:51+0200 [basketsp17] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.euroleague.net/features/blog/2013-2014> (referer: http://www.euroleague.net/main/results/by-date)
```

But after several times it stopped crawling. I want to know where is the problem. If I try code next day it works again for several moments and stops. Well, it works but it doesn't crawl. If I change start_urls it starts to work again and it stops again with the same code.
What could be wrong here?

Here is what I see after it stops:

```
scrapy crawl basketsp17
2013-11-22 03:07:15+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.20.0 started (bot: basketbase)
2013-11-22 03:07:15+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto, django
2013-11-22 03:07:15+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'basketbase.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['basketbase.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'basketbase'}
2013-11-22 03:07:16+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2013-11-22 03:07:16+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2013-11-22 03:07:16+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2013-11-22 03:07:16+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: 
2013-11-22 03:07:16+0200 [basketsp17] INFO: Spider opened
2013-11-22 03:07:16+0200 [basketsp17] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2013-11-22 03:07:16+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2013-11-22 03:07:16+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2013-11-22 03:07:16+0200 [basketsp17] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.euroleague.net/main/results/by-date> from <GET http://www.euroleague.net/main/results/by-date/>
2013-11-22 03:07:16+0200 [basketsp17] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.euroleague.net/main/results/by-date> (referer: None)
2013-11-22 03:07:16+0200 [basketsp17] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2013-11-22 03:07:16+0200 [basketsp17] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 489,
     'downloader/request_count': 2,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 12181,
     'downloader/response_count': 2,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
     'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 22, 1, 7, 16, 471690),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 8,
     'log_count/INFO': 3,
     'response_received_count': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 22, 1, 7, 16, 172756)}
2013-11-22 03:07:16+0200 [basketsp17] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Here is a code that I am using:

```
from basketbase.items import BasketbaseItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.http import TextResponse 
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse


class Basketspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "basketsp17"
    allowed_domains = ["www.euroleague.net"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.euroleague.net/main/results/by-date/"]
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('main\/results\/showgame\?gamecode\=/\d$\&seasoncode\=E2013\#!boxscore')),follow=True),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()),callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def init_request(self):
        return HtmlResponse("http://www.euroleague.net/main/results/by-date/", body = body)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        items=[]
        item = BasketbaseItem()
        item['date'] = sel.select('//div[@class="gs-dates"]/text()').extract() # Game date
        item['time'] = sel.select('//div[@class="gs-dates"]/span[@class="GameScoreTimeContainer"]/text()').extract() # Game time

        items.append(item) 
        return items
```

Comment: I will be interested how you tackled this problem. Please let me know. Thank.s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the code of yours to make it work. The changes,

I don't see the purpose of init_request, at least I don't think anybody is calling it.

Overriding the parse of the CrawlSpider and changing the response to HtmlResponse before passing it to the base parse.

Again changing the response to HtmlResponse in the parse_item

Please understand that we are blindly converting response to HtmlResponse. At least you should check that response is type "Response" and if possible check for html tag in body before converting it to HtmlResponse.(Other checks scrapy does, but fails). Also, may be this conversion may be neatly handled in downloadmiddleware. If may try converting it Response in the process_response method, subject to , that process_response is handled before the , call_back of the spider.

```
#from basketbase.items import BasketbaseItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.http import TextResponse
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse


class Basketspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "basketsp17"
    allowed_domains = ["www.euroleague.net"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.euroleague.net/main/results/by-date/"]
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('main\/results\/showgame\?gamecode\=/\d$\&seasoncode\=E2013\#!boxscore')),follow=True),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()),callback='parse_item'),
    )  

    def init_request(self):
        print 'init request is called'
        return HtmlResponse("http://www.euroleague.net/main/results/by-date/", body = body)

    def parse(self,response):
        response = HtmlResponse(url=response.url, status=response.status, headers=response.headers, body=response.body)
        return super(Basketspider,self).parse(response)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        response = HtmlResponse(url=response.url, status=response.status, headers=response.headers, body=response.body)
        sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        items=[]
        print 'parse item is called'
        #item = BasketbaseItem()
        #item['date'] = sel.select('//div[@class="gs-dates"]/text()').extract() # Game date
        #item['time'] = sel.select('//div[@class="gs-dates"]/span[@class="GameScoreTimeContainer"]/text()').extract() # Game time

        #items.append(item) 
        return items
```

I think this problem of yours is both a combination of the site not following standard and scrapy not using body to build the reponse. I think we should raise this issue with scrapy either as a enquiry or issue.